# Removing white status bar box

Tags: swift, xcode

When opening up my side menu on my app, the status bar shows with a white background and even if I hide the status bar in the entire app it shows the white part. Is there an easy way to remove this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nobody could answer your question without more information.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to change simulated matrices. Click view controller and then change status bar to default. Then the status bar will visible in the storyboard also. Then you can add a view underneath of the status bar or you can remove it without white space. Hope that this will gonna help you :)

[image]